# C# to check if the current login user have contributor access for SP site

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, development, permissions, spsite, check-permissions

I need to check the currently logged in user having the create list permission or not.

suggest some idea .

Answer (score 3):

Inside your web part / application pages, you could add some helper methods, like:

```
private bool CouldCurrentUserManageLists()
{
    SPUser user = SPContext.Current.Web.Url;
    using (SPSite site = new SPSite("http://yourspsiteurl"))
    {
        using (SPWeb web = site.OpenWeb())
        {
            return web.DoesUserHavePermissions(user.LoginName, SPBasePermissions.ManageLists));
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use **DoesUserHavePermissions** method to check user permission. below is the code snippet to use this method.

```
   if (web.DoesUserHavePermissions(SPBasePermissions.PermissionwhichYouWanttoCheck))
   {
       //Your Code
   }
```

Below are the permissions which can be checked web level
Web level permission
**Open

ViewPages

AddAndCustomizePages

ApplyThemeAndBorder

ApplyStyleSheets

ViewUsageData

CreateSSCSite

ManageSubwebs

CreateGroups

ManagePermissions

BrowseDirectories

BrowseUserInfo

AddDelPrivateWebParts

UpdatePersonalWebParts

ManageWeb
UseRemoteAPIs

ManageAlerts

CreateAlerts

EditMyUserInfo**